# Would an assignment listed in the method cause a memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I would like to know if the possible resetting of amounts in the populateResponse() can cause a memory leak.    This class intent is to be used to process web service requests. My understanding is the BigDecimal created at (i) will be considered a local object instance if the call to padAmount() returns a new BigDecimal and will fall out of scope after the method execution and will be marked for GC. 
Is this correct?

```
public SampleResponse processRequest(SampleRequest request){
        BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("12.3000"); // this will pad
        //BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("12.35"); // this will not pad, but return passed in amount
        return this.populateResponse(amount);

    }

    public SampleResponse populateResponse(BigDecimal amount){
        BigDecimal finalAmount = new BigDecimal(amount.toString(), new MathContext(21));
        SampleResponse response = new SampleResponse();
        response.setRespAmount(finalAmount.setScale(6, RoundingMode.UP).stripTrailingZeros()); //(i) Setting an amount
        Integer newScale = 2;
        BigDecimal paddedAmount = this.padAmt(newScale, finalAmount);
        response.setRespAmount(paddedAmount); //(ii) Possible reset of amount. Will this cause a memory leak if the paddedAmount has a new memory address
        return response;

    }
    public BigDecimal padAmt(int newScale, BigDecimal amount) {

        String amtWoTrailingZeros = amount.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
        try {
            int decDigitsInAmt = this.getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(amtWoTrailingZeros);
            if(newScale > decDigitsInAmt){
                System.out.println("Pad amount with zeros");
               return new BigDecimal(amtWoTrailingZeros).setScale(newScale);
            }else {
                System.out.println("No Need to pad amount with zeros");
                return amount;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception caught here: " +e);
            return amount;
        }

    }

    public int getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(String decimalNumber) throws Exception{
        if (decimalNumber == null){
            throw new Exception("decimal number is NULL");
        }
        int index = decimalNumber.indexOf(".");
        return index < 0 ? 0 : decimalNumber.length() - index - 1;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        RequestProcessor rp = new RequestProcessor();
        SampleRequest request = new SampleRequest();
        SampleResponse response = rp.processRequest(request);
        System.out.println("Sample response amount: " +response.getRespAmount().toPlainString());
    }
```

Comment: Your code is completely stateless. It doesn't store anything in any instance or static field. How could it leak memory?

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the code. I was getting confused since I was possibly overwriting the response.setRespAmount() with a new BigDecimal (for cases that needed the padding) and I was not sure if the previous value that this attribute pointed would be marked for garbage collection after the method call. In the actual code the response object is a Jaxb object (ReturnAmountType) that has the following:

Comment: continued from the previous comment..In the actual code the response object is a Jaxb object (ReturnAmountType) that has a BigDecimal @XmlElement(required=true)
  protected BigDecimal finalRoundedAmount;. This return amount type is added to a new Response Object and sent back to the caller for subsequent marshalling.

Comment: That's exactly what the garbage collector is for: it collects the memory used by objects which are not reachable anymore, like the BigDecimal previously stored in your object.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and for your review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think there's a memory leak, you should be able to trigger an OutOfMemoryError by running the offending code in some loop. But it seems there are no leaks here!

From this comment in your code

> Will this cause a memory leak if the `paddedAmount` has a new memory address?

it seems you are very confused about what memory leaks are: there's a leak when memory no more *needed* by the application is still *used* by the program. In order to have a memory leak there needs to be some long living object (either application-defined or language-defined, like Class, so watch out for `static` fields!) with either a heavyweight field (a byte array, native memory, whatever) or a field that stores a collection of objects and is not properly cleared.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing and your suggestions. I have posted the reason for my confusion in my comment to JB Nizet. Thanks again

Comment: given the nature of code I have, I understand there will be more objects  (that don't have any long living references)for GC on completion of the local methods. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you asked

Comment: Basically that when I possibly reset the response.setRespAmount() with a new BigDecimal (from the call to the padamount()), the previously stored BigDecimal value becomes eligible for GC after the completion of the method populateResponse()

Comment: It becomes eligible if it's not referenced anymore by any other object

Comment: Thanks. I thought so but was not sure.